# Break a row into muliple rows based on the (string) content of a column

Tags: python, pandas

One column of my dataframe has a variable number of `\n`s inside its content and I need each line to be on a single row on the final dataframe.

This is a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x', 'y'], 'b':['line 1\nline 2\nline 3', 'line 1' ]})
```

That produces this starting dataframe:

```
    a   b
0   x   line 1\nline 2\nline 3
1   y   line 1
```

I want it to become like this one:

```
    a   b
0   x   line 1
1   x   line 2
2   x   line 3
3   y   line 1
```

I've seen there is a built in function that converts each `pattern` to a new column with the `str.extract` command below, for example, this is what I tried:

```
df['b'].str.extract(pat='(.*)\n(.*)', expand=True)
```

That produces a somewhat interesting output:

```
    0       1
0   line 1  line 2
1   NaN     NaN
```

But this is not a viable solution, because the data is split over columns and not rows, not all patterns matched and it's not clear how to put it back on the original dataframe in place and order. The order of the entries is relevant to be preserved, although the `dataframe index` is not.

In order to capture all the patterns, it would be possible to do this:

```
df['b'].transform(lambda x: x.split('\n'))
```

That yields this output:

```
0    [line 1, line 2, line 3]
1                    [line 1]
```

But again, I don't see a way to make progress from this to the desired state.

Comment: If using pandas >0.25 use the explode method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `str.split` and `explode`

```
df = df.set_index('a').b.str.split('\\n').explode().reset_index()

Out[153]:
   a       b
0  x  line 1
1  x  line 2
2  x  line 3
3  y  line 1
```

---

**For pandas < 0.25**

```
df = (df.set_index('a').b.str.split('\\n', expand=True).stack()
                         .droplevel(1).reset_index(name='b'))

Out[174]:
   a       b
0  x  line 1
1  x  line 2
2  x  line 3
3  y  line 1
```

Comment: This is perfect. Unfortunately, I'm on pandas `0.24.2` right now, so this doesn't work, but I'm accepting the answer, anyways, thanks.

Comment: @JairoAlves: I added solution for pandas < 0.25. Check the edited